# Sound plays with latency in flash and air as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, air

I'm developing a piano app in as3; however, I get too much latency.

I am using short WAV files from my flash library (not streaming) and loading the files in the constructor. I tried also working with MP3 files but I get the same latency.

I understand that developers know about that and there are a lot of threads regarding it but no one really solves the issue.

Does anyone know a workaround in order to reduce the latency?

There is a solution that says to play a silent sound all the time to prevent the sound mixer going to sleep. I tried it and it didn't work (or maybe I  did it wrong).

Here is the code, it's just a simple code to test the latency

```
 package 

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;


public class SoundLatencyMain extends Sprite 
{   
public var MainSoundChannel:SoundChannel;
public var playbutton:MovieClip;
public var TheSound:Sound;
public var bgmusic:Sound;
public var bgsoundboolean:Boolean;

public function PlayBGMusic(me:MouseEvent):void
{
    MainSoundChannel = bgmusic.play();
}

public function PlaySound(me:MouseEvent):void
{
    MainSoundChannel = TheSound.play();
}

    public function SoundLatencyMain()
{

MainSoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

playbutton = new PlaybgMusic_MC();
playbutton.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
playbutton.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
addChild(playbutton);


               playbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, PlayBGMusic);
bgmusic = new BGMusic();
TheSound = new TestSound();
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, PlaySound);

    }

}
```

Comment: are your mp3 samples fading in? That could be a reason why. I personally never noticed latency on Desktop, is it for mobile device?

Comment: Show us some code. Are you using key presses or mouse events?

Comment: Have you tried running the app outside of the Flash IDE? I remember struggling w/ a problem like this that turned out to only occur when testing the movie in the IDE, but was fine when I ran the swf on its own.

Comment: thank you for your help, i am using wav files cause mp3 files has a second silence at the start of the file. when i test the app on my pc its ok, the latency is fine, but when i test it on my android device the latency is far far worse. i tried to play a long silent sound in loop to prevent the audio engine to go to sleep but nothing  make it better. does anyone has an answer for a workaround that actually work? im stuck with more then 2 projects because of that :(